# Dropdown using select with bootstrap is open in the middle

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

this is my code:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedCustomer" ng-options="c.name for c in customers" ng-change="show()">
                </select>
```

and this what happens: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdhaH.png)

i tried to wrap it with div but it doesnt help.

thanks for your help

Comment: You may need to use bootstrp with Angular js Bindings Here is a link to a library https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @EvansDianga its doest help. it happens when i choose any option from the list

Comment: Could you show  your controller and view?